# Unable to find match using contains in query in Googlesheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hey i have some information i want to get from sheet2 which has dates domains and count. I want it to be for a specific month which I enter in sheet4 under cell A3. And im grouping this by domain. To get the total count for a domain for that specific month. I tried using Contains but it doesn't retrieve the information when I set 01/2021 for instance in cell A3.

The formula which you can check in B2 is

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A:D,"SELECT SUM(A),B WHERE D CONTAINS '"&$A$3&"' GROUP BY B")
```

I made it work by formula in G1

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({ Sheet2!A:C,MID(Sheet2!D:D,4,2)},"SELECT Sum(Col1),Col2,Col4 WHERE Col4='"&$A$2&"' GROUP BY Col2,Col4"))
```

Not sure which Locale is the sheet but dates should be dd/mm/yyyy.
Any ideas why this one `=QUERY(Sheet2!A:D,"SELECT SUM(A),B WHERE D CONTAINS '"&$A$3&"' GROUP BY B")` isn't doing the trick?

sheetlink
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dAyJSoWui7aFqnQgn_M7bEn2-hRP-ak6eC9jBFiPPgY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The dates are in mm/dd/yyyy format. You can check that with the `day()` or `month()` functions.

Comment: ztiaa is correct. And since your dates are in mm/dd format, there are no matches for May in the current list.

Comment: Yeah you're right I was switching between accounts and got lost on the locale. Formatted them both to text and it worked. I'm pretty there's better ways to do it but still thought that one should have worked. Now it does. Cheers guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ztiaa and Erik pointed the date wasn't formatted properly (mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).